# difference between from x import y and import x.y

Tags: python, import

So I am confused as what the difference is...Here is some code to display my confusion:

```
>>> import collections.OrderedDict as od
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named OrderedDict
>>> from collections import OrderedDict as od
>>> od
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

## explanation:

`import collections.OrderedDict` did not find the module, yet `from collections import OrderedDict` found it?! **What is the difference between those two statements?**

the class is read as `collections.OrderedDict`, so I don't understand why the first attempt was unable to find the module

## note:

I am simply using [collections](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) as an example. I am not looking for specifically why my example acted the way it did for collections, but rather an explanation for what the different lines of code are actually requesting as far as imports go. If you would like to include an explanation on the error, feel free! Thanks!

Comment: `OrderedDict` is a class within the `collections` module. When you see things like x.y and something is being imported from it, that means that "y" in this case is actually a module.

Comment: oh so basically y would be a directory inside x in the scheme of things where otherwise y is a class or function inside the module?

Comment: you can nest modules within modules, yes.

Comment: i knew that, I just didn't realize that this was actually different syntax

Comment: Hey, no worries. It actually made me pause as well. Great question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OrderedDict` is a class within the `collections` module. When you see things like x.y and something is being imported from it, that means that "y" in this case is actually a module.

You should read the docs about how `import` works: [here](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/import.html). It's long and involved but at the same time fairly straight forward in how it looks into the different packages and modules to find what should be brought into play. Specifically, the import [statement](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) itself and [import system](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/import.html#importsystem).

Answer (score 5):

[PEP 221](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/) talks about `import as`.

```
import foo.bar
```

is for importing a *submodule* `bar` of the module `foo`.  This can be 'imported as'

```
import foo.bar as fb
```

An object is imported

```
from foo import baz
```

This, too, can be 'imported as'

```
from foo import baz as fb
```

`collections.OrderedDict` is not a submodule but an object so it can only be 'imported as' in the second way.