# Pytest : How to set on my pytest configuration(conftest) to run on a test environment?

Tags: python, pytest, python-importlib

I thought the easy way was to reload the config module with my software environment as 'Testing'.

My code has a `config.py` which works as configuration handling code where I define all my configuration setting per each environment I'd like to run.

**config.py**

```py
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True

config_lookup = dict(
    testing=TestingConfig(),
    development=DevelopmentConfig(),
    production=ProductionConfig(),
)

config = config_lookup[os.getenv('ENVIRONMENT', 'development')]
```

**One approach could be using reload:**
On my `conftest.py` I would like to make ensure that all my tests would run as per TestingConfig.
Therefore I would do something like this:

**conftest.py**

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def cfg():
    # Reload the global 'config' instance.

    os.environ["ENVIRONMENT"] = "testing"
    importlib.reload(sys.modules["config"])
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't seem to work as expected for all situations as the `importlib.reload()` seems to perform expected.

> `importlib.reload()` Reload a previously imported module. The argument must be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before.
> Read more:[importlib Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

This solution may work in the first instance but it will become tricky when using a different type of imports.(object vs submodule)

An object is imported

```py
from app.config import config 

print('Environment is:',type(config).__name__)

# Environment is:Development <- Wrong
```

An module is imported

```py
import app.config as _ 

print('Environment is:',type(_.config).__name__)

# Environment is:Testing <-- correct
```

Another approach  is to ensure you always set your environment variable when executing pytests:
`ENVIRONMENT=testing python -m pytest tests`

Not a desirable as you might forget to append your environment.

Related issues:

[difference-between-from-x-import-y-and-import-x-yPython Bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue34309)

[Change environment variables before importlib.reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767517/change-environment-variables-before-importlib-reload)

[Reloading All Loaded Modules](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch14s02.html)

[difference-between-from-x-import-y-and-import-x-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668831/difference-between-from-x-import-y-and-import-x-y)
[pep-0221](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/)

Comment: It's not clear how this is failing or what behavior you are looking for. Could you please [edit] to clarify what the actual question is here?

Comment: @tripleee, thanks. I added more context.. in fact, the given approach works but is not reliable as it may fail depending on how you decide to import your configuration along with the different development features. A developer might decide to import `from x import y` and this will fail.

Comment: So your problem is that `reload` does not recursively reload everything imported by a module? That's a common FAQ and a duplicate then.

Comment: Well I've describe a problem from one approach I have tried but my issue is just to ensure that I can set a conftest properly to run under a test environment.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that seems to work quite well is to ensure that you set your environment before running `conftest.py`. Is using [python-env](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env)

```
[pytest]
env =
    ENVIRONMENT=testing
```

Seems to work fine. The upsidedown is that is an old repository without maintenance but is also a small piece of code.